# Piping histograms in dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, histogram

Is it possible to pipe multiple graphs in dplyr.

This is working:

```
birdsss = data.frame(x1 = 1:10,x2 = 21:30,x3 = 41:50)
birdsss%>%  
  with(hist(x1, breaks = 50))
```

but this is not working:

```
birdsss%>%  
  with(hist(x1, breaks = 50)) %>%  
  with(hist(x2, breaks = 50)) %>%  
  with(hist(x3, breaks = 50))
Error in hist(x2, breaks = 50) : object 'x2' not found
```

I've also tried:

```
birdsss%>%  
  with(hist(x1, breaks = 50)) &  
  with(hist(x2, breaks = 50)) &  
  with(hist(x3, breaks = 50))
```

and

```
birdsss%>%  
  with(hist(x1, breaks = 50)) ;  
  with(hist(x2, breaks = 50)) ; 
  with(hist(x3, breaks = 50))
```

What could be the solution to print multiple columns in one line?

Something like:

```
 birdsss%>%  
      with(hist(x1:x3, breaks = 50))
```

I'm using a longer pipe (filter(), select(), etc.) and what to finish with multiple graph. I simplified the code here.

Comment: I love dplyr, but `lapply(birdsss, hist, breaks = 50)` is a lot easier. Use `purrr`'s `map` or `walk` if you really want a tidyverse version.

Comment: The thing is that I'm constrain by the code I'm using because I'm also using filter(), select() etc. That's why I thought using apply inside the pipe... but it wasn't working either.

Comment: It's really not one or the other; base and tidyverse play perfectly well together. You can chain into `lapply` if you like, e.g. `birdsss %>% lapply(hist, breaks = 50)`. And if you're going full tidyverse, use ggplot2 and just facet: `birdsss %>% tidyr::gather() %>% ggplot(aes(value)) + geom_histogram(bins = 51) + facet_wrap(~key)`

Comment: Cool! I wasn't "lapplying" the right way! Is it possible to change the title of the graphs inside the lapply function. I've tried main = c("something1","something2","something3"), but it's not working

Comment: Since you're now trying to pass two arguments in parallel, you could use `mapply`/`Map` for a multivariate version (or the various `purrr` versions like `map2`/`walk2`, which chain a little more easily). Here, maybe `Map(function(x, y){hist(x, breaks = 50, main = y)}, birdsss, names(birdsss))`, or a `purrr` version: `walk2(birdsss, names(birdsss), ~hist(.x, breaks = 50, main = .y))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `lapply`

To put some of my comments from above into an answer, the simplest way make a histogram of each variable is

```
# let's put them in a single plot
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))

lapply(birdsss, hist, breaks = 50)    # or chain into it: birdsss %>% lapply(hist, breaks = 50)

# set back to normal
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

This does mess up the labels, though:

[image: lapply plot]

#### `Map`/`mapply`

To fix this with base, we'd need to iterate in parallel over the data and the labels, which can be done with `Map` or `mapply` (since we don't care about results—only the side effects—the difference doesn't matter):

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))

Map(function(x, y){hist(x, breaks = 50, main = y, xlab = y)}, 
    birdsss, 
    names(birdsss))

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image: Map plot]

Much prettier. However, if you want to chain into it, you'll need to use the `.` to show where the data is supposed to go:

```
birdsss %>% 
    Map(function(x, y){hist(x, breaks = 50, main = y, xlab = y)}, 
        ., 
        names(.))
```

---

#### purrr

Hadley's `purrr` package makes `*apply`-style looping more obviously chainable (and though unrelated, working with lists easier) without worrying about `.`s. Here, since you're iterating for the side-effects and want to iterate over two variables, use `walk2`:

```
library(purrr)

walk2(birdsss, names(birdsss), ~hist(.x, breaks = 50, main = .y, xlab = .y))
```

which returns the exact same thing as the previous `Map` call (if you set `mfrow` the same way), though without useless output to the console. (If you want that information, use `map2` instead.) Note that the parameters to iterate over come first, though, so you can easily chain:

```
birdsss %>% walk2(names(.), ~hist(.x, breaks = 50, main = .y, xlab = .y))
```

---

#### ggplot

On a completely different tack, if you're planning on sticking everything in a single plot eventually anyway, ggplot2 makes making related plots very easy with its `facet_*` functions:

```
library(ggplot2)

# gather to long form, so there is a variable of variables to split facets by
birdsss %>% 
    tidyr::gather(variable, value) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(value)) + 
        # it sets bins intead of breaks, so add 1
        geom_histogram(bins = 51) + 
        # make a new "facet" for each value of `variable` (formerly column names), and 
        # use a convenient x-scale instead of the same for all 3
        facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image: ggplot version]

It looks a bit different, but everything is editable. Note you get nice labels without any work.

Answer (score 8):

The normal pipe `%>%` pipes the left hand side to the right hand side. `hist` returns a (very useful) `hist` object, but it's not data that you can pipe to another histogram. You want the "T" pipe:

```
library(magrittr)
birdsss %T>%  
  with(hist(x1, breaks = 50)) %T>%  
  with(hist(x2, breaks = 50)) %T>%  
  with(hist(x3, breaks = 50))
```

This will pipe whatever came before the first "T" to whatever comes after. See [the magrittr documentation](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) for details.

Comment: Wow, never heard of the T pipe! This is probably life changing.

Comment: I mean, I found the regular pipe somewhat life-changing, but the T pipe is just a novelty. If you *really* want an intermediate plot in the middle of a chain it can be useful, but I generally think it hurts readability - I'd rather break the chain, make the plot, and continue.

Comment: That said, if you're into this sort of thing, I think you'll find the assignment pipe `%<>%` more useful than the T pipe.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

birdsss <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, x2 = 21:30, x3 = 41:50)

my_hist <- function(x) { 
  hist(x$val, breaks=50, xlab=x$var[1], main=sprintf("Histogram of %s", x$var[1]))
}

par(mfrow=c(3,1))
birdsss %>% 
  gather(var, val, x1, x2, x3) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  do(a=my_hist(.)) %>% 
  invisible()
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: I shld have noted that this'd be "cleaner" if using `geom_histogram()` but I try not to force that on folks who give primary example in base graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
attach(birdsss)

hist(x1,breaks = 50)
hist(x2,breaks = 50)
hist(x3,breaks = 50)

detach(birdsss)
```

Or probably better:

```
with(birdsss,{
        hist(x1,breaks = 50)
        hist(x2,breaks = 50)
        hist(x3,breaks = 50)
     }

     )
```

I remember reading somewhere that using `attach` can lead to confusion.

Comment: `attach` is a filthy habit and should be discouraged.

Comment: @Gregor, yeah as I mentioned I remember reading about it, but I have never fully understood the perils of `attach`. Can you suggest a source that explains that clearly?

Comment: I don't know a good source, but my big problems with attach are 1) if you already have objects in your global environment with the same names as your column names it can cause bugs 2) if you do anything at all complicated after attaching it's very easy for columns to get out-of-sync (one column gets rearranged, or loses a couple rows, etc) 3) your attached columns get out of sync with your data frame. Overall, I think the convenience is small (`with` works just about as well, and neither is needed for functions that take a `data` argument), but the potential problems are large.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep this completely within `dplyr` you can simply use the `select` function to select the variables you wish to generate histograms for using the solution below:

```
hist((birdsss %>%  
  select(x1:x3)), breaks = 20)
```